# How can I feed input within bash [Executed through the Network]

Tags: linux, bash, input, debian

As the title says, within linux how can I feed input to the bash when I do `sudo bash`

Lets say I have a bash script that reads the name.

The way I execute the script is through sudo using: 
`cat read-my-name-script.sh | sudo bash`

Lets just say this is how I execute the script throught the network.

Now I want to fill the name automatically, is there a way to feed the input. I tried doing this: `cat read-my-name-script.sh < name-input-file | sudo bash` where the `name-input-file` is a file for the input that the user will be using to feed the script.

I am new to linux and learning to automate the input and wanted to create a file for input where the user can fill it and feed it to my script.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but the `cat read-my-name-script.sh | sudo bash` design causes some embarrassment. You can make your `read-my-name-script.sh` executable `chmod +x read-my-name-script.sh` and run it via `sudo ./read-my-name-script.sh`

Comment: I wanted to run the script without downloading it, this is because I will put the source somewhere online.

Comment: You want to read the content of `name-input-file` and pass this as argument for the script or it his name must passed to the script as argument?

Comment: It could contain multi-number of reads within the script, the name input was just an example but in reality it is like 5+ inputs.

Comment: Please update your question with the content of `read-my-name-script.sh` and `name-input-file`. Please also clarifies what you mean by _I execute the script throught the network_

Comment: What does "executed through the network" mean here, is it just superfluous information or do you need for this to be embedded into a more-complex `ssh` command line?

Comment: @tripleee What I meant exactly about being executable within the network is to fetch the script as text and then run that script with sudo bash. It is the same as running `cat` but in in actual situation it would be `curl`.

Comment: That's probably worthy of including in the question, if only to make it clearer what the phrase means.

Comment: Which machine (user or server) should the main script run on? And for which of the machines should the actions described in the script be applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is convoluted, but might do what you want.

```
sudo bash -c "$(cat read-my-name.sh)" <name-input-file
```

The `-c` says the next quoted argument are the commands to run (so, read the script as a string on the command line, instead of from a file), and the calling shell interpolates the contents of the file inside the double quotes before the `sudo` command gets evaluated.  So if `read-my-name.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "I want your name please"
```

then the command gets expanded into

```
sudo bash -c '#!/bin/bash
read -p "I want your name please"' <name-input-file
```

(where of course at this time the shell has actually removed the outer double quotes altogether; I put in single quotes in their place instead to show how this would look as actually executable, syntactically valid code).

Comment: what is -c doing in this command can you please explain, as far as i know it helps in setting up more options but can't figure out what its doing in your command

Comment: This works on using the cat, just need more explanation on how this thing works.

Comment: Updated answer; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need that:

```
while read -r arg; do sudo bash read-my-name-script.sh "$arg";done <name-input-file
```

So each line of `name-input-file` will be passed as argument to `sudo bash read-my-name-script.sh`

If your argslist located on http server, you can do that:

```
while read -r arg; do sudo bash read-my-name-script.sh "$arg";done < <(wget -q -O- http://some/address/in/internet/name-input-file)
```

**UPD**

add `[[ -f name-input-file ]] && readarray -t args <name-input-file`
to `read-my-name-script.sh`
and use `"${args[@]}"` as arguments of command in the script.
For example `echo "${args[@]}"` or `cmd "${args[0]}" "${args[1]}" ... "${args[100]}"` in any order.

In this case you can use
`wget -q -O- http://some/address/in/internet/read-my-name-script.sh | bash`
for run your script with arguments from `name-input-file` whitout saving script to the local machine

Comment: I am not grabbing the input from the web, it is the other way around. The script is the one that is grabbed from the web.